# Remove one parameter from the query string without using regex

Tags: java, spring, string, servlets, request

So I have a URL which is

```
String url = request.getRequestURL()+"?"+request.getQueryString();
```

There is a parameter Custom="true", which i want to remove before i store it in url.
Is there any efficient way to do this, without using regex.

```
Example - 

 http://myhost:8080/people?lastname=Fox&age=30&Custom=true&verified=yes

 request.getQueryString();  // "lastname=Fox&age=30&Custom=true&verified=yes"

Desired o/p - lastname=Fox&age=30&verified=yes
```

Comment: please provide example value of queryString

Comment: `request.getQueryString().replace("Custom=true&", "")` may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `Custom=true` with empty String

```
query = query.replace("Custom=true&","");
```

Comment: I guess you did not understand the question, request.getQueryString() already returns string after ?. from that resulting string which is lastname=Fox&age=30&Custom=true&verified=yes" , I want to remove Custom=true

Comment: It will replace otherCustom=true& too

Comment: Parameters are unique so that will not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace exact match,below code will work.

```
String url = "http://myhost:8080/people?lastname=Fox&age=30&Custom=true&verified=yes";
    String newUrl = "";
    String[] splits = url.split("&");
    for(String split : splits) {
        if(!"Custom=true".equals(split)) {
            newUrl = newUrl+"&"+split;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work if "Custom" is the only parameter in query string

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that relies on Java 8 Streaming API:

```
    StringBuffer requestUrl = request.getRequestURL();
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();

    String[] queryStringParts = queryString.split("&");

    String newQueryString = Stream.of(queryStringParts)
            .filter(p -> !p.equals("Custom=true"))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

    String newUrl = StringUtils.hasText(newQueryString) ?
            requestUrl.append("?").append(newQueryString).toString() :
            requestUrl.toString();
```

Also the fact that request url and query string are initially separate (as stated in the question) actually helps.